# Java Client/Server connection using Amazon EC2 server

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, client-server

I'm trying to write a client/server application with the server side being hosted on an Amazon EC2 server running Ubuntu.  The server works locally, but I can't seem to get it to work on the EC2.  I can tell that it's opening a port, as it's supposed to, by using netstat.  However, every time I try to connect, the Client program catches an IOException.

The way I'm getting the IP address of the server is from the Public DNS address given by Amazon.  I'm assuming that if Amazon gives you ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com  then XX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the public IP address.  Is this correct?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In ec2, all instances are part of a security group which acts as an external firewall. Is the correct port open in the security group? Some AMI's also have software firewalls running (iptables) that also need to be opened.

Comment: That was the problem! I didn't have the inbound rules set to allow that port to be open.  Thanks datasage!